# How to get data from mongodb using _id.$oid object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am trying to find objects with logged-in user id.

```
function getItems(req, res) {
    var userId = JSON.stringify(req.user._id);

    Items.find({user_id: userId}, function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            res.json(items);
        }
    }); 
}

// Logged-in user
app.get('/userItems', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    getItems(req, res);
});
```

User json data looks like:

```
"_id": {
     $oid": "55c772bce97e9a500b3754ae"
}
```

Item object is such:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55d086a182377f840844ee78"
    },
    "user_id": "55c772bce97e9a500b3754ae",
    itemSpecs:[
        //...
    ]
}
```

It returns empty array because userId doesn't match to user_id I guess. As I try to set:

```
var userId = '55c772bce97e9a500b3754ae';
```

It returns the items with the userId.

```
var userId = JSON.stringify(req.user._id);
console.log(typeof userId); // >> String
```

So, userId from user object and user_id from items object are same type: String.

Probably this is really stupid but I can't see the reason why the user **_id** object doesn't match to **user_id** in items object.

How could I get items which have logged-in user id with using logged-in user id from _id.$oid object?

Comment: What this means is that you imported your data incorrectly. The `$oid` here was **meant** to be translated into an [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) BSON type instead of what you have here. Read about [extended json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) in the core documentation. The [`mongoimport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/program/mongoimport/) utility also correctly handles such data natively.

Comment: var userId = req.user._id.toString(); solved it thnx!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `JSON.stringify(req.user._id);`, you get string which is the JSON representation of an ObjectID object. It should be something along the line of `"{ "$oid": "55c772bce97e9a500b3754ae" }"` which is not the same string as `"55c772bce97e9a500b3754ae"`.

To get just the hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId, use  `req.user._id.toHexString()`.

By the way, for manual references between documents, using actual ObjectID's is more efficient than using hex strings. A raw ObjectId is 12 byte while a 24 character hex string is 28 byte.

Comment: req.user._id.toHexString() works but not req.user._id.$oid.